# Microsoft Graph API: What does ExtensionError: Operation: Create; Exception: [A task was canceled.] mean?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, subscription

I am attempting to create a subscription to Outlook messages for a user.

```
{
    "resource": "/users/<userid>/messages",
    "change_type": "created,updated"
}
```

The Graph API responds with a `500` error.

```
{
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [A task was canceled.]",
    "innererror": {
        "client-request-id": "1ecf5f0f-9d6e-4ba0-86d1-8890f42508f2",
        "date": "2023-09-14T16:45:09",
        "request-id": "1ecf5f0f-9d6e-4ba0-86d1-8890f42508f2"
    }
}
```

This typically works without any issues. I have recently begun seeing this error sometimes. I am getting it every time for at least one specific `user_id`.

Here is a list of headers from a request:

```
Cache-Control:[no-cache]
Client-Request-Id:[1ecf5f0f-9d6e-4ba0-86d1-8890f42508f2]
Content-Type:[application/json]
Date:[Thu, 14 Sep 2023 16:45:09 GMT]
Request-Id:[1ecf5f0f-9d6e-4ba0-86d1-8890f42508f2]
Strict-Transport-Security:[max-age=31536000]
Vary:[Accept-Encoding]
X-Ms-Ags-Diagnostic:[{
    "ServerInfo": {
        "DataCenter": "West US 2",
        "Slice": "E",
        "Ring": "1",
        "ScaleUnit": "004",
        "RoleInstance": "MW2PEPF0000E062"
    }
}]
```

What does `Operation: Create; Exception: [A task was canceled.]` mean?

Comment: POMS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1368708/what-does-extensionerror-operation-create-exceptio?comment=question#newest-question-comment

Answer (score 0):

Have had a support case with Microsoft relating to this issue for the last few months. It was escalated to the engineering team, and ultimate case response was that the target mailbox is busy and the request should be retried later